# Would a parallax measurement of distance to a star be affected by relativistic length contraction?

Tags: special-relativity, astronomy, parallax

Let's say you had 2 ships launched 1 light year apart towards a star 10 ly away and they were equidistant from the star moving at .6c towards it. Would their velocity cause their parallax distance measurements to see a length contracted distance to the star? I ask this because length contraction occurs when using time to measure length but parallax measurements of distance are not dependent on time (I believe). So I would conclude that the parallax measurements in this example would not be affected by velocity and would not show any evidence of length contraction of the distance to the star. Yes?

Comment: I looked up aberration of light is not the same as parallax but how would the astronauts be able to differentiate between the two in their measurements?

Comment: The parallax angle will be different (larger) because the star is closer

Comment: The parallax angle would rather be smaller (than observed by observers at rest with respect to the star), because relativistic aberration tilts the visible position of light sources further away. Due to Lorentz – contraction of moving observer’s ruler (if we consider the stars as "stationary") apparent distance in the direction of travel would be increased.

Comment: @Albert you got it wrong

Comment: Why? It goes out straight from relativistic aberration formula. Due to relativistic aberration, light sources are collected in a heap in the direction of the observer's movement. Feynman Lectures, 34-8. Relativistic aberration https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_34.html Please note, that distances in direction of travel increase. In the frame of "stationary" observer the same effect is known as light - time correction. There is a delay since speed of light is finite, hence displacement of apparent position, we see moving star "in the past".

Comment: @Albert But here the motion is towards the star, the apparent distance will be smaller, not larger, it is the same as length contraction

Comment: I did not consider the finite speed or light, I assumed you would see the star in the actual position, I am not sure if this would introduce some correction

Comment: Should be smaller but it is larger :).  You see, the distance to the star may depend on the clock synchronization pattern. Einstein synchronization leads to contraction of distances, anisotropic synchronization leads to expansion  This is where it becomes clear that in a moving reference frame, synchronization must be anisotropic. Some thoughts are here , particularly in the chapter Reichenbach's synchr
 https://www.pitt.edu/~jdnorton/teaching/HPS_0410/chapters/significance_conv_sim/index.html . It's a pity that Norton completely forgot to mention relativistic aberration in this chapter!

Comment: I will check you references, but I dont think that length contraction will depend on synchronization

Comment: It does the same way as time dilation depends on synchrony convention, read it here in the chapter non-standard synchronization https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_speed_of_light *As required by the experimentally proven equivalence between Einstein synchronization and slow clock-transport synchronization, which requires knowledge of time dilation of moving clocks, the same non-standard synchronisations must also affect time dilation. It was indeed pointed out that time dilation of moving clocks depends on the convention for the one-way velocities used in its formula.*

Comment: I don't see how sync between clocks would be an issue because the ships can be launched independently and the angles measured can be compared in post processing. Wouldn't each ship just be the muon example?

Comment: It is not synchronization of start - time. See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacetime Definitions, read corresponding text close to fig. 1-1. *“The 'observer' synchronizes the clocks according to their own reference frame”* I mean that different synchronization schemes according to different one – way speeds of light lead to different outcome of measurements. So as to "make" the star to be not closer, but further (as this observer sees by telescope) this observer must synchronize clocks in his own frame accordingly,  so as to align measurements by clocks to observations by telescope.

Comment: Just like the earth looks closer in the muon example, so would the star look closer and hence the angle of the telescope would be larger hence the parallax measurement would be affected by the velocity as opposed to stationary observers from the same point.

Comment: No Willo, no. Why would you come to those unreal conclusions? Those situations do not evaporate, they are changed by subsequent actions. You've developed a real personal dislike to me haven't you? Why not stick to the discussion or don't. I am not trolling you by posting am I?

Comment: A mirage looks like water so long as the conditions exist that created the mirage. But it never really was water, it was an illusion of water. D'ya feel me now? Are all my posts really worth a down vote mostly from you? Nothing interesting at all in any of them? You make me feel very unsafe.

Comment: If I may, and I've had experience with this on other forums, I think your genuine disagreement with everything I have to say has morphed into a hatred of anything I have to say. There's a line between power and abuse of power and your continual down votes and close votes have become an obsession for you. Maybe step back and take a look at this from my perspective. Maybe recuse yourself from reading my questions and posts and allow others opinions on them to have more weight. The more I try to dig myself out of this banishment hole, the more dirt, tainted with bias, you throw on.

Comment: A carpet is unrolled when a force is applied to it in the right way, and rolled back up when another force is applied.  A rod contracts when a force is applied to it in the right way, and lengthens when another force is applied.  How do you imagine that pushing on one end of a rod is any less "real" than pulling on one end of a carpet?

Comment: Questions should not be edited in a way that would invalidate existing answers. If you have a new question, ask a new question. If you are not being allowed to ask new questions at this time, trying this restriction by editing old questions this way will not make things better.

Comment: Here's a technical problem:  A parallax measurement of the distance to a star requires a base line (at righr angle to the line of sight) on the order of one astronomical unit.

Comment: How's this edit @Chris? "Could a parallax measurement of distance to a star physically confirm relativistic length contraction?" By removing my text you've invalidated Willo's comment. The question has evolved based on the other non-committal answers here because the original form was going nowhere. I'm supposed to improve my questions. Would you prefer I just wait out my time because what I was supposed to do is what no one wants me to do. What about the flag I raised, was removing my edits the response?

Comment: If you have not yet, read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86998/380389) in its entirety. You are encouraged to *improve* your questions with regard to grammar and clarity and the like, but not to alter your questions into new ones entirely. If you can not improve your old questions, you can try answering other people's questions. Besides that all you can do is wait out the restriction.

Comment: Oh Willo you're back. You wish to have a philosophical discussion on the nature of reality. I'm not sure of your point of view on length contraction but I assume you're saying a steel rod is like a spring and while a force is contracting it, it's contracted and when the force evaporates, the spring goes back to normal length. I don't know how to create a chat room.

Comment: Furthermore, once the spring returns, it doesn't mean the reality of it being contracted is erased. Hence, my assertion that reality requires persistence must be horse-hockey in your book. Let's say from my perspective, across a football field, you're only 2 inches high. This is an illusion of perspective. I can compensate for this to come at the truth. However, if you moved towards me and remained 2 inches high, that would be contrary to physics.

Comment: But this is exactly what happens in the twin paradox with time but not with length. You would return to me permanently younger but not shorter or flatter. The effects on time persist but those on length only exist on record, they do not persist and so I do not define them as real but an illusion of perspective. You don't like that but it was not the conclusion of my question. What I had found out was length contraction can be measured in real time against a real ruler. That's significant to me but you want to talk philosophy instead.

Comment: Of course the effects on length persist, unless and until you apply different forces to the two ends of the rod so as to either stretch or compress it.    What else could cause its length to change?  That's physics, not philosophy.

Comment: Relativity of simultaneity. The length doesn't actually change. Are we talking about the same thing? Length contraction in relativity?

Answer (score 1):

Assume the origin of the coordinate is system is at the Sun,  the  earth is orbiting the Sun in the xy plane, the star is at a distance L along the z-axis, and the radius of the earth’s orbit is r.  When the earth is at y=-r, an astronomer on earth points a little arrow at the star on the celestial sphere.  When the earth is at y=+r, the astronomer must rotate the little arrow in the y z plane by  $\theta_x$  so the arrow points to the star’s new location on the celestial sphere.  If an observer is now boosted by $\lambda$ toward the star, we can calculate the new angle and boost parameters that the boosted observer sees done to the arrow.

\begin{align}
\Theta{'} & = \begin{bmatrix}  
1 & 0 &              0 &              0 \cr
0 & 1 &              0 &              0 \cr
0 & 0 & \cosh{\lambda} &-\sinh{\lambda} \cr
0 & 0 &-\sinh{\lambda} & \cosh{\lambda} \end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
  0 &         0 &        0 & 0 \cr
  0 &         0 & \theta_x & 0 \cr
  0 & -\theta_x &        0 & 0 \cr
  0 &         0 &        0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}  
1 & 0 &              0 &              0 \cr
0 & 1 &              0 &              0 \cr
0 & 0 & \cosh{\lambda} & \sinh{\lambda} \cr
0 & 0 & \sinh{\lambda} & \cosh{\lambda} \end{bmatrix}\\ \cr
&=\begin{bmatrix}
  0 &   0 &                         0 &                         0 \cr
  0 &   0 &  \theta_x \cosh{\lambda}  &  \theta_x \sinh{\lambda}  \cr
  0 &   -\theta_x \cosh{\lambda}  & 0 &                         0 \cr
  0 &    \theta_x \sinh{\lambda}  & 0 &                         0 \end{bmatrix}\\ \cr
&=\begin{bmatrix}
  0 &    0 &                       0 &                      0 \cr
  0 &    0 &        \theta_x \gamma  &  \theta_x \beta\gamma  \cr
  0 &           -\theta_x \gamma & 0 &                      0 \cr
  0 &  \theta_x \beta\gamma  & 0 &                          0 \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
Therefore, the new parallax angle is $ \theta_x{'}=\gamma \theta_x$.  The new observer could understand this as

\begin{align}
\theta_x{'}   &=\gamma \theta_x       \cr \cr
\frac{2r}{L'} &=\gamma \frac{2r}{L}   \cr \cr
         L{'} &=\frac{L}{\gamma}
\end{align}
So the boosted observer is correct in saying  the new parallax angle is the diameter of the orbit divided by the Lorentz contracted distance $L{'} $  to the star.

Comment: Ok that is the correct and factual answer to my OP. But if I may go a bit further, is the contraction an illusion of perspective or is the star physically pulled forward by the line of contracted space between the moving ship and the star (which was the new part of my question which was removed).

Comment: I don't think "illusion" or "star is physically pulled" are good concepts as to how L behaves.  You may be led to unworkable conclusions like fictitious forces acting on the star.  Here is an example to make the contraction of L seem more real to you.  Your spaceship is going close to c toward the star.  Via redshift of lines you see the star approaching you at close to c.  Via the parallax measurement you conclude the star is the contracted L' away.  What makes L' even more real is that it takes you ~$\frac{L'}{c}$ seconds of your life to get to the star …. no illusion!

Comment: Sure but anything you ascribe to length contraction can be ascribed exclusively to time effects. The point of the question is whether there's a length-only yardstick. The parallax measurement is that but it's undermined by the effects of relativity of simultaneity (RoS) otherwise fictitious or illusory forces causing actual shrinkage are being invoked as you said. Slowed time is also illusory as RoS affects the relative start of time measurement, not its rate. I'm pretty sure no one agrees with my last statement even though I have the math to support it.

Comment: This feels like I'm jumping into an existing discussion you are having to which I can't add much.  My only 2 cents is that physics seeks to mathematically copy what we measure with a minimal set of ideas.  If more than one word story can decorate that math, fine, but I wouldn't choose to get lost in philosophy seeking which is really true.

Comment: Yes an existing discussion where everyone is telling me an iron bar is forcibly being shrunk by the energy imparted to get to the velocity or by quantum effects ellipsizing spherical electron orbits in the iron atoms. My math says the RoS between a travelling object relative to a stationary observer will cause the observer to start his stopwatch later than when his perspective said the worldline began. https://photos.app.goo.gl/4b6UpRjw7U29pMgC6 . The blue perspective starts his stopwatch 1.8 sec after he determines the race started but both  agree the race took 3.2s of stationary time.

Comment: RoS = vx/c^2. It is like the distance between them has  time value of 1.8s in my example which is like a head start in the race, related to these equations (ct')^2=(ct)^2 - x^2 (or (ct")^2 = (ct')^2 - (x/Y)^2 from the moving perspective). The RoS is not the time dilation rate of time but a lump sum of time that is the difference between race start and timing start. v'=Yv=x/t'=6/4c which is the distance moved / proper time on the moving ship. That's why it takes less time in your ship to reach the star not because length contraction is real.

Comment: As you said, math trumps philosophy but the simplest math wins.

Answer (score 0):

The ships should discount the effect of the aberration, because they are moving fast in relation to the stars to be measured.

But once made the corrections, the parallax angle would show the expected length contraction.

I think the issue of synchronization is part of the length contraction calculation.

Comment: My misinterpretation was you either apply parallax calculations or length contraction but the correct answer is parallax calculations are applied on top of a moving frame perspective and will differ from those taken from a stationary perspective. Sorry, amateur mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I made an edit to this question that would give it more relevance to a useful concept but the edit was removed. There is an obsession on wikipedia of whether some physical ruler could be held up to something long whizzing past and being able to determine that the moving object has physically shrunk due to length contraction. There is all kinds of supposed evidence that the results of certain particle collisions do not make sense if the particles hadn't have contracted before the collision. In a previous question, I had hoped Raskar photography, with its femtosecond frame resolution would be that physical ruler but the frame resolution is not enough to detect length contraction.

This led to this question and indeed the parallax measurement does present a physical ruler, independent of time, to measure reciprocal length contraction. The physical ruler is the distance to a star and due to relative velocity, the ships can be viewed as the stationary frame and the distance to the star is whizzing past them. The parallax view, which is independent of time, does indeed measure the distance to a far off star as having length contracted, from the ships' perspective, due to the velocity of the ships approaching that star. But the fact that it's impossible that the velocity of a ship can shrink space all the way to the star and physically pull it towards them must mean that length contraction is an illusion of perspective caused by relativity of simultaneity. The star would only look closer due to a trick of time, not due to a length physically contracting.

Comment: Your word "illusionary" seems synonymous with any measurement of the rod's length not done in the rod's rest frame.  The idea that the rest frame length of the rod is invariant under boosts is well known.  You are correct, the invariant length of the rod (or invariant distance to the star) does not change just because we look at it from a boosted frame.  In this sense, measurements of the rod's length in other reference frames is illusionary, and we must return to the rest frame of the rod to measure its "real" length.  I am still thinking about your idea of Persistence.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I wish I could shove your comment in the face of everyone who says otherwise. The rest frame length is invariant. So frustrating when everyone else I've ever come across disagrees. I do have a problem without knowing the correct terms to use as my Loedel age difference post shows.

Comment: Here is a link to a good portion of my math explaining why the time effect persists. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/526395/can-light-signals-be-used-to-tell-the-time-they-were-sent-from-both-perspective . The 2nd half of the math has been erased and I can't repost it until my ban expires in 5 months but I do have it.

Comment: If you wish to comment on someone else's answer, you should post a comment on their answer, not edit your own. If you want to post an extensive comment, or have a prolonged discussion with someone, feel free to make a chat room for that purpose

Comment: I should have included that the invariant length $ds$ is the length $ds^2=dx^2+dy^2+dz^2-dt^2$ of the 4-vector $(dx,dy,dz,dt)$ between two spacetime points.  In the rod's rest frame take these two spacetime points to be at the ends of the rod at the same time (so $dt=0$). Then $ds=L$.  In a boosted frame the 4-vector between these same two spacetime points will be $(dx',dy',dz',dt')$ and $ds'=ds=L$ still. But $dt' \neq 0$.  So the observer chooses a different spacetime point for one end of the rod such that $dt'=0$, measures the new length $ds'=L' $, and reports a Lorentz contracted L'.

Comment: I read the faq, don't see how to start a chat room. @Gary Godfrey So yeah, whether 4-vector or Lorentz transforms, space and time are interchangeable and there's always a proper perspective and a boosted one. That's why my Loedel perspective is so cool because it simulates a common proper length and time perspective for both participants simultaneously. If you want to chat I'll make a room but if not they'll delete all I'll put into it if no one responds. Or you can wait 5 months until the brief interlude before my next banishment.

Comment: My point is as soon as you accept all perspectives are equally real, you ignore the underlying objective reality of proper time and proper space from which all perspectives are derived and hence illusory. The Loedel perspective and its beautiful math gives you a window into the underlying reality. Heresy I know and it's a shame I can only present the vast amount of math in small erasable chunks. Math is not a personal theory, it's a language to convey meaning as I lack the terms to use the relativistic language. I hope Chris will open that chat room now. Makes it easier to delete my stuff.

Comment: If space and time are interchangeable in equations, why is there no instance of persistence in length as there is for time? People argue the persistence exists because c would be exceeded in near c travels to distant stars without length contraction. This is false because v=x/t not x/t'. Travel is at Yv =x/t', which is the invariant distance in the time on your spaceship, not in Earth time; no violation of c, no evidence of length persistence. I remember this being a Breme or Epstein concept but I see nothing on wiki about this.