# Length contraction, reciprocity and measures of distance

Tags: special-relativity, parallax

In [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/525589/would-a-parallax-measurement-of-distance-to-a-star-be-affected-by-relativistic-l), it is explained that parallax measurements of distance are affected by length contraction. This should be true on both ends, since movement is relative and not absolute, and that appears to create contradictions in some scenarios.

Consider 3 spaceships disposed roughly in a straight line: A  B  C
and assume they are big enough and close enough to measure their distances using parallax (for instance by extending sensors from both sides of a ship) and capable of very fast accelerations and speeds. They start at relative rest and all agree on their respective distances. Now C starts moving toward (or away, I think length contraction doesn't care) B and A at relativistic speed high enough that (AC)' < (AB).
It seems A can get contradictory information about the distance to C. On one hand by parallax it is now closer than B, but on the other B can still occlude the light from C, etc.

What am I missing? Do we get the same contradiction if we measure the distance to C by relative photometry (it's got a beacon of known intensity) and correct for relativistic beaming?

Comment: How do you get parallax if everything is moving in a single line?

Comment: @Dale If the spaceships are big and not too far you can directly observe their angular size and compare to their known specs. Otherwise extend sensors from both sides of your ship or whatever. I think whether this is feasible in practice is not relevant to the theoretical question.

Comment: I think the sensors to the side is a good approach. The angular size is not parallax. I would recommend that you put that into the question for clarity

Comment: @Dale I made the edit, thanks. Measuring the angular size might not be exactly the same thing, but I think it's analogous enough that it would respond in the same way to length contraction, no?

Comment: I don’t know. I have not worked out the math on this. But I suspect (without having done the math) that they might be different. Parallax compares the position of a nearby object to a distant object, but the nearby object can be a point. The angular size requires the object to not be a point and makes no reference to distant objects

Comment: I did work out the math and put in a  answer about the Lorentz transformation of solid angle.

Comment: @JEB I can't see your answer. Or do you mean it's in an answer to a different question?

Comment: @Alexbib it's a different question, and I don't know how to link it.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is really simple:

When observer O sees that spaceship C starts moving while C being next to planet P, then observer O sees that C starts moving at the distance of P. And O sees that C's distance to O starts changing at the speed that C moves, multiplied by Doppler effect.

When O sees that C is next to P, then O sees that parallax of C is same as parallax of P. Obviously.

Comment: Isn't that saying that parallax doesn't care about relative speed then? This is initially what I thought would happen, but it seems to contradict the answer to the other question I linked to.

Comment: @Alexbib Yes. Parallax doesn't care about relative speed.

Answer (score 0):

The simple formula for length contraction applies only for intervals whose endpoints are at rest relative to one another. If A and C are moving relative to one another, then the distance (AC) depends on time, which means you need to take time dilation and the relativity of simultaneity into account. In other words, you need to bring in the full Lorentz transform, applying it to specific well defined events in spacetime. For example, consider what happens as C passes B. If A measures the distance AC at that time, then there are events $A_0$ and $C_0$ which correspond to the positions of A and C at some particular time $t$ in A's reference frame, and (AC) is the spatial component of $A_0-C_0$. If C measures the distance AC while passing B, then similarly there are events $A_1$ and $C_1$ corresponding to some particular time $t'$ in C's reference frame, and (AC)' is the spatial component of $A_1 - C_1$. It's easy to see that $C_0 = C_1$ (they're the same event, the intersection of B's and C's world lines). But $A_0$ and $A_1$ are *not* the same event, so (AC) and (AC)' are different.

As an aside, the use of parallax to measure the distance is a red herring. *Any* accurate method of measuring distance will be subject to the same length contraction.